# use database is giving the error message

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> show databases;

ERROR 1018 (HY000): Can't read dir of '.' (errno: 13)
```

I have installed the mysql-server using

```
apt-get install mysql-server as root.
```

If I issue command to use other  database  than mysql it is working properly

```
mysql> use mysql;

ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'mysql'
```

what the issue please help.

Comment: Do you have a database called `mysql`?

Comment: Every MySQL installation has a mysql database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL may be installed, but no database inside (altough it'd be weird).

Try to issue mysql_install_db.

```
PATH_TO_MYSQL/scripts/mysql_install_db --user=mysql
```

Check this out: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/unix-postinstallation.html

Answer (score 1):

To fix this, I added `open-files-limit = 2048` to the `[mysqld]` context in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

Restarted mysql and all came good.

Check: http://i-learnings.blogspot.com.au/2012/11/error-1018-hy000-cant-read-dir-of-errno.html

Answer (score 0):

You should check your datadir. To find out where MySQL stores data:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'datadir';
```

Check that directory. It should be owned by mysql.mysql, same for all directories below. Privileges should be `drwx------`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is caused by this bug. http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=15851
The suggested fix is to update the directory permissions.